# Filtering task results and task results depth in Flower for monitoring Celery workers

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, flower

I process millions of tasks/day with celery workers and rabbitmq and I would like to only keep the failed tasks as history.

The problem is that there is so much tasks being processed that the failed tasks keep getting deleted.

In the mean time, history in kept for success tasks for which I have limited interest.

Is there a solution to keep all the failed tasks for longer ?